# Problema al capturar checkBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

estoy queriendo aplicar un evento en el momento que el checkbox cambia. Si hago un forEach de mi variable me trae el Array de mis input tipo checkbox, pero cuando quiero aplicar la addEventListener('change') esto no hace nada.

Adjunto codigo

Vista

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">F. Carga</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
                    <th scope="col">$ Valor</th>
                    <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Estado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($comprobantes as $comprobant)
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><span>{{$comprobant->created_at}}</span></td>
                    <td>{{$comprobant->cliente->name}}</td>
                    <td class="text-success">$ {{ moneyPesos($comprobant->price) }}</td>
                    <td>{{$comprobant->user->name}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <input class="form-check-input check" type="checkbox" id="{{$comprobant->id}}" {{$comprobant->status==1?'checked':''}}>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            {{ $comprobantes->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Codigo JS

```
const checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'].check");
checks.forEach((check, i)   =>  {
    check.addEventListener('change',()  =>  {
        console.log(check,i);
    })
});
```

En la consola no aparece nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe poniendo el console log debajo del forEach

```
const checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
checks.forEach((check, i) => {
    console.log(check, i);
});
```

y me arroja esto la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consol.log antes del ForEach

```
const checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
console.log(checks);

checks.forEach((check, i) => {
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuevo test
Copie y pegue parte del codigo en la parte superior donde no se ve afectada por ningun tipo de plantilla de blade ni CSS alguno que pueda interferir y ahi si funciona, pero cuando se le aplica la capa de renderizacion de blade no funciona

Comment: Tal como planteas el problema, no se puede reproducir. [Acá dejo una demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tjh2ge1r/)

Comment: Y porque en ese ejemplo si? Cual es la diferencia?

Comment: Eso es imposible que lo podamos saber. Quizás la tabla se recarga dinámicamente... a lo mejor los `input` en algún momento pierden la clase `.check`... existen infinitas posibilidades. Intenta crear un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,
mira lo que sucede es que tu estas tratando de obtener checkbox con la clase check, pero esta no existe, para que te funcione tendrías que agregarle la clase check a todos los checkbox a los que quieres agregar el evento o podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
const checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
checks.forEach((check, i) => {
    check.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log(check, i);
    })
});
```

en lo personal si no tienes más checkbox en la página lo haría general.

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer y sigue sin generar nada en la consola.

Comment: Aparte fíjate que en los input esta agregada la clase check

Comment: en que parte estas cargando el script que debe agregar los eventos?, el escript debe cargarse justo despues que termines de renderizar todos los checkbox a los que deseas agregarles el evento, el problema tal vez es que no encuentra los checkbox, trata de ejecutar un console.log a checks antes de iniciar el foreach, para saber si esta detectando elementos

Comment: Al final de la web. Antes de cerrar la etiqueta body

Comment: Fijate Jesus que ahi edite el post y puse el console.log debajo del forEach para que vea que si recupera los input

Comment: Franco, lo que sucede es que tienes que poner el console.log antes de declarar el forEach, ya que si la constante checks no tiene valores para recorrer, ese console.log nunca se va ejecutar, primero crea un console.log justo debajo de la constante checks, imprimiendo esta y con esto sabremos si esta detectando o no los inputs para agregarles el evento

Comment: Ahi lo agregue, fijate que la variable Checks si tiene datos

Answer (score 0):

Luego de aplicar el comando make:auth se me genero la carpeta Layouts con el archivo app.blade.php, el cual posee un div con id="app".
Tuve que borrar el div. Si alguien sabe para que sirve este div por favor que me avise

```
<body>
<div id="app">
@include('layouts.navbar')
<main class="py-4">
    @yield('content')
</main>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

@yield('script')
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Blade es un sistema de plantillas y no incluye por defecto nada salvo que tú lo escribas, puedes ser más claro por favor?

Comment: Ahi edite la respuesta con mas detalles